# Difference between std::unordered_map < K, boost::ptr_deque < T > >'s operator[] (K const &) and emplace

Tags: c++11, boost, unordered-map, noncopyable, boost-ptr-container

```
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_deque.hpp>

struct T
{
    T() = default;
    T(T const &) = delete;
    T & operator = (T const &) = delete;
    T(T &&) = default;
    T & operator = (T &&) = default;
};

using S = boost::ptr_deque < T >;

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map < uint32_t, S > testum;
    //  testum.emplace(1u, S());
    //  testum.insert(std::make_pair(1u, S()));
    testum[1].push_back(new T());
}
```

In the above example, the commented out lines don't compile as they try to copy elements of the `ptr_deque` which are non-copyable.  However, the `push_back` form works.

I was thinking that `operator [] (K const &)` is simply `return emplace(k, mapped_type()).first->second` or `return insert(value_type(k, mapped_type())).first->second`, which is essentially the commented out statements

Apparently that is not the case.  Does `operator []` perform some `placement new` magic internally?

Or is there something special about `ptr_deque`?

I am using gcc-6.1 & boost 1.59

Comment: Try also `testum.emplace( std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(1u), std::make_tuple() );`

Comment: Thanks.  If this had been a reply, I would voted up & marked as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at :

> 2) Inserts a `value_type` object constructed in-place from
>   `std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(key)), std::tuple<>()`
>   if the key does not exist.

(I'm referring to the `Key&&` overload since in the commented out line, you're using an rvalue as an argument to `operator[]`.  Though in the case of `Key=int` the difference is pretty much trivial.)

So in reference to your question, `operator[](Key&&)` is roughly equivalent to

```
return emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
               std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(k)),
               std::tuple<>()).first->second;
```