# vector of pair of non-copyable-non-movable-type and emplace_back

Tags: c++11

This is essentially a follow up to my earlier question [Difference between std::unordered_map < K, boost::ptr_deque < T > >'s operator[] (K const &) and emplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130787/difference-between-stdunordered-map-k-boostptr-deque-t-s-operator)

I am trying to implement a associative vector (call it unordered_flat_map) and would like to support `operator [key]`

Here is the code...

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

struct T
{
    T() = default;
    T(T const &) = delete;
    T & operator = (T const &) = delete;
    T(T &&) = delete;
    T & operator = (T &&) = delete;
};

using S = T;

int main()
{
    using value_type = std::pair < uint32_t, S >;
    std::vector < value_type > testuvm;
    value_type p(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(2), std::forward_as_tuple());
    //  testuvm.emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(2), std::forward_as_tuple());
}
```

The commented out line fails to compile, which is what `unordered_map::operator []` does if the key is not found.  Is there a way to make this work?  If not, why is this not possible?  Is this due to a limitation of `vector`?

Comment: I've added reference to std::deque. Might be interesting...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In documentation of [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), note the requirement for the type to be [MoveInsertable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveInsertable).

While `emplace_back` does not move the new element, it might still need to move the *existing* elements when it reallocates the storage. So there is no practical way to use a vector with immovable type.

Note that [`std::deque::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/emplace_back) does *not* have that requirement and should be, with some care, usable.

Or, if you need to use `vector`, you can wrap the type in [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to make it movable.

Comment: Thanks.  But this is a very specific use case where I need it to be a `vector`

Comment: @zrb, if it has to be a `vector`, then you'll have to make the type movable. By wrapping it in a `std::unique_ptr` if nothing else helps.